# Asp.net mvc5 . async await. wait on task with diff return types

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I just started working with .net mvc 5 async await . I have few tasks which i determine at run time  to run parallel . All of them have different return types and i want to use Task.WhenAll to wait on them. Like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197699/awaiting-multiple-tasks-with-different-results) discusses, but i don't have the predefined set of tasks to run . I need to create a collection of tasks with different return types at run time 
and wait .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create a `List<Task>` and then use `Task.WhenAll`:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
var task1 = Func1Async();
tasks.Add(task1);
var task2 = Func2Async();
tasks.Add(task2);
...

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Note that since the return types differ, you have to pull the results out individually:

```
var result1 = await task1;
var result2 = await task2;
```

Comment: Like i said , i don't know how many tasks are going to be in the collection. so i cant do this "var result1 = await task1;
var result2 = await task2;"

Comment: May be something like this but in c# .https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android/issues/13

Comment: @user1803361: Then you just use `dynamic`, as such: `var results = tasks.Select((dynamic x) => x.Result);`

Comment: thank you @Stephen Cleary . Could you throw some light on how we handle exceptions (one or more tasks failed) in this case ? . Thanks again :)

Comment: The `await Task.WhenAll` line will throw an exception if one or more tasks fail.