# Getting return values from Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

Hopefully a fairly simple one here. I have a collection of objects, each of which has an async method that I want to call and collect values from. I'd like them to run in parallel. What I'd like to achieve can be summed up in one broken line of code:

```
IEnumerable<TestResult> results = await Task.WhenAll(myCollection.Select(v => v.TestAsync()));
```

I've tried various ways of writing this without success. Any thoughts?

Comment: How does `TestAsync` look?

Comment: This line of code looks OK. What doesn't work exactly? Any compiler error, run-time exception, etc.?

Comment: I guess his `TestAsync()` signature was looking like this: `public async TestResult TestAsync()`, instead of `public async Task<TestResult> TestAsync()`.

Comment: Somewhat related: [ForEachAsync with Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907650/foreachasync-with-result).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If the tasks you're awaiting have a result of the same type `Task.WhenAll` returns an array of them. For example for this class:

```
public class Test
{
    public async Task<TestResult> TestAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000); // Imagine an I/O operation.
        return new TestResult();
    }
}
```

We get these results:

```
var myCollection = new List<Test>();
myCollection.Add(new Test());

IEnumerable<TestResult> results = await Task.WhenAll(myCollection.Select(v => v.TestAsync()));
```

Comment: @I3arnon: this is the same code, which OP had written. It's better to clarify, what doesn't work for him.

Comment: I've explained what should work and why. I'm waiting for the OP to clarify what doesn't work for him.

Comment: I'm an idiot - My TestAsync method was returning a Task rather than a Task<TestResult> - as soon as I changed that, it worked. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction - I couldn't see what was wrong even though it was riht in front of me!

Comment: Could you supply an example where `TestAsync` accepts parameters, and is a `static` method ?

Comment: What worked for me was replacing `Task.WaitAll` with `await Task.WhenAll` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25319520/1684720)

Answer (score 4):

Do it like this:

```
public async Task RunMultipleTasksInParallelAsync()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task<MyResultType>>(); //<---- Add the return type here

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var task = DoSomethingAsync();
        tasks.Add(task);
    }

    var myResults = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

public async Task<MyResultType> DoSomethingAsync()
{
    return new MyResultType();
}
```

Recogize that you have to add the return type into the task list, otherwhise Task.WhenAll will have the return type **void**.

Comment: Thank you! That was the missing piece of the puzzle for me