# ForEachAsync with Result

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreachasync

I'm trying to change [Stephen Toub's](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync-part-2/) `ForEachAsync<T>` extension method into an extension which returns a result...

Stephen's extension:

```
public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int dop, Func<T, Task> body) 
{ 
    return Task.WhenAll( 
        from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(dop) 
        select Task.Run(async delegate { 
            using (partition) 
                while (partition.MoveNext()) 
                    await body(partition.Current); 
        })); 
}
```

My approach (not working; tasks get executed but result is wrong)

```
public static Task<TResult[]> ForEachAsync<T, TResult>(this IList<T> source,
    int degreeOfParallelism, Func<T, Task<TResult>> body)
{
    return Task.WhenAll<TResult>(
        from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(degreeOfParallelism)
        select Task.Run<TResult>(async () = 
        {
            using (partition)
                while (partition.MoveNext())
                    await body(partition.Current); // When I "return await",
                        // I get good results but only one per partition 
            return default(TResult);
        }));
}
```

I know I somehow have to return (`WhenAll`?) the results from the last part but I didn't yet figure out how to do it...

**Update:** The result I get is just `degreeOfParallelism` times null (I guess because of `default(TResult)`) even though all the tasks get executed. I also tried to `return await body(...)` and then the result was fine, but only `degreeOfParallelism` number of tasks got executed.

Comment: "Result is wrong" really doesn't describe what you're seeing at all. The fact that you're returning `default(TResult)` doesn't seem like a good start. It would help if you'd provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, including sample input, expected output and actual output. (I strongly suspect you want `SelectMany` instead of `Select` here, basically...)

Comment: @JonSkeet: added an update

Comment: Couldn’t you make a list where you add your results to that you then return at the very end after everything finished?

Comment: @poke: thought of that too but I believe this is not really async-like?!?

Comment: It doesn't help that the code you've posted currently wouldn't compile...

Comment: @JonSkeet: I'm sorry, somehow brackets got not copied and pasted... I should now work...

Comment: Nope, you appear to have a parameter of type `Func<T>` with no name. Again, if you'd posted a short but complete example to start with, you could be confident that it would be compile because it would be your exact code.

Comment: @JonSkeet: My bad, I apologize... updated it again.

Comment: @Dunken: Are you absolutely sure you need a parallel *and* asynchronous foreach? Parallel implies CPU-heavy code, and asynchronous implies I/O-heavy code. Yours is both? If you are in this (very rare) situation, consider using TPL Dataflow.

Comment: @StephenCleary: good question... I believe yes. Actually I want to stress-test an API (I also want to measure the throughput). I first went with tasks only but this overwhelmed my system (to many HTTP connections?). Because of this I now switched to the current solution which allows me to call my API a few thousand times with a fixed number of concurrent calls... Do you agree?
Thanks for the hint. I do have to admit I don't know it very well but I think it's worth digging in...

Comment: You can achieve throttling for asynchronous code via `SemaphoreSlim`. I just tend to avoid parallel code unless there's a need for it (i.e., CPU-heavy code, which is not the case here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your LINQ query can only ever have the same number of results as the number of partitions - you're just projecting each partition into a single result.

If you don't care about the order, you just need to assemble the results of each partition into a list, then flatten them afterwards.

```
public static async Task<TResult[]> ExecuteInParallel<T, TResult>(this IList<T> source, int degreeOfParalleslism, Func<T, Task<TResult>> body)
{
    var lists = await Task.WhenAll<List<TResult>>(
        Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(degreeOfParalleslism)
            .Select(partition => Task.Run<List<TResult>>(async () =>
                    {
                        var list = new List<TResult>();
                        using (partition)
                        {
                            while (partition.MoveNext())
                            {
                                list.Add(await body(partition.Current));
                            }
                        }
                        return list;
                   })));
     return lists.SelectMany(list => list).ToArray();
}
```

(I've renamed this from `ForEachAsync`, as `ForEach` sounds imperative (suitable for the `Func<T, Task>` in the original) whereas this is fetching results. A `foreach` loop doesn't have a result - this does.)

Comment: Oh right, keep the lists in the synchronous part, and return lists. That’s good! Guess I wasn’t too far off after all.

Comment: @JonSkeet: doesn't compile (list.Add instead of results.Add) but it's still not working

Comment: @Dunken: I've fixed the `list.Add`, but please give more information than "it's still not working" - that really doesn't provide much for me to go on. (Again, if you'd provided a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, it would have been easier for me to test it for myself...)

Comment: @JonSkeet: I meant it still doesn't compile... I'm working on an example... For now: The await operator in the 3rd line can only be used within an async method...

Comment: @DunkenL: Okay, if you'd said that before I'd have fixed it immediately - the method just needs to be an async method. *Always* say what the error is, rather than just "it doesn't work".

Comment: @Dunken: Doh, typo. Should be async instead of await. Try now... will try compiling it myself, too...

Answer (score 8):

Now that the [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) API has become part of the standard libraries (.NET 6), it makes sense to implement a variant that returns a `Task<TResult[]>`, based on this API. Here is an implementation that targets .NET 8:

```
/// <summary>
/// Executes a foreach loop on an enumerable sequence, in which iterations may run
/// in parallel, and returns the results of all iterations in the original order.
/// </summary>
public static Task<TResult[]> ForEachAsync<TSource, TResult>(
    IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    ParallelOptions parallelOptions,
    Func<TSource, CancellationToken, ValueTask<TResult>> body)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(parallelOptions);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(body);
    List<TResult> results = new();
    if (source.TryGetNonEnumeratedCount(out int count)) results.Capacity = count;
    IEnumerable<(TSource, int)> withIndexes = source.Select((x, i) => (x, i));
    return Parallel.ForEachAsync(withIndexes, parallelOptions, async (entry, ct) =>
    {
        (TSource item, int index) = entry;
        TResult result = await body(item, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
        lock (results)
        {
            if (index >= results.Count)
                CollectionsMarshal.SetCount(results, index + 1);
            results[index] = result;
        }
    }).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<TResult[]> tcs = new();
        switch (t.Status)
        {
            case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
                lock (results) tcs.SetResult(results.ToArray()); break;
            case TaskStatus.Faulted:
                tcs.SetException(t.Exception.InnerExceptions); break;
            case TaskStatus.Canceled:
                tcs.SetCanceled(new TaskCanceledException(t).CancellationToken); break;
            default: throw new UnreachableException();
        }
        Debug.Assert(tcs.Task.IsCompleted);
        return tcs.Task;
    }, default, TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach |
        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap();
}
```

This implementation supports all the options and the functionality of the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` overload that has an `IEnumerable<T>` as `source`. Its behavior in case of errors and cancellation is identical. The results are arranged in the same order as the associated elements in the `source` sequence.

The [`CollectionsMarshal.SetCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.setcount) is an advanced API that was introduced in .NET 8. It alters the `Count` of a `List<T>`, exposing uninitialized data when increased. For a less modern (and slightly less performant) approach that runs on .NET 6, see the [5th revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71129678/5) of this answer.

Comment: Nice! There should be an overload built-in with an index parameter to the delegate. The only thing I would change at first glance: I would use a `ConcurrentDictionary<int, TResult>`  instead of a `List<TResult>` and I would remove the `lock`.

Comment: @Asotos the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` overload with indices sounds like a legit idea. You could consider submitting an [API suggestion](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/new/choose) to the dotnet/runtime repository. I would give it a ~10% chance to be accepted (after a few years of deliberations). As for switching to a `ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>` for storing the results, it is also a valid idea. I avoided it because it will immediately increase the memory consumption, while the performance benefits will be most likely negligible.

Comment: The `Parallel.ForEach` already has such an overload, so it might be added eventually.

Comment: @Asotos it might, but don't hold your breath. The evolution of .NET APIs is a slow and hesitant process. :-)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Followed a thread of SO questions, answers and comments from you to get here.  In a different attempt to implement a ParallelForEachAsync you commented about CancellationToken usage here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136542/parallel-foreach-with-asynchronous-lambda/68901782#comment127207976_66635760.  I'm surprised to not see any 'check for is cancelled' in the code above.  Could you explain how that works?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias On the same ParallelForEachAsync solution, you commented about `WhenAll` being suitable for small number or never throwing error here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136542/parallel-foreach-with-asynchronous-lambda/68901782#comment117797299_66635760.  I have approximately <= 25 REST calls I need to make.  I just want to either await all results or cancel as soon as the first one fails (cancelling all other requests).  Best practice is to just use this method and set degreeOfParallellism to the size of my 'task list'?

Comment: @Terry the cancellation here is handled by the native `Parallel.ForEachAsync` itself. If you want to cancel the parallel operation, you can configure the `CancellationToken` property of the `ParallelOptions`. Regarding how to configure the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` property, there is no one-fits-all rule, because it is highly dependand on the capabilities of the hardware, network etc that does the actual work. I have posted some suggestions about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34359509/factors-for-determining-the-degree-of-parallelism-for-the-foreachasync/75432732#75432732).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thanks for the info.  I've posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76501926/best-way-to-handle-async-await-and-cancellation to try and explain what I want.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Why not open a PR to dotnet/runtime for this?

Comment: @JohnZabroski at least one proposal already exists: [API Proposal: Provide a result returning Parallel.ForEachAsync overload](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/72489).