# Factors for determining the degree of parallelism for the ForEachAsync

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreachasync

Below is an implementation of `ForEachAsync` [written by Stephen Toub](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync-part-2/).

```
public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int dop,
    Func<T, Task> body) 
{ 
    return Task.WhenAll( 
        from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(dop) 
        select Task.Run(async delegate { 
            using (partition) 
                while (partition.MoveNext()) 
                    await body(partition.Current); 
        })); 
}
```

What factors should be considered when specifying a partitionCount (`dop` in this case)?

Does the hardware make a difference (# of cores, available RAM, etc)?

Does the type of data/operation influence the count?

My first guess would be to set `dop` equal to `Environment.ProcessorCount` for general cases, but my gut tells me that's probably unrelated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both hardware as well as operations executed matter a lot.

If you want to run CPU bound work that is not constrained in any other way you don't need to method at all. You're better off using `Parallel` or `PLINQ` which are made for that (and suck terribly at IO).

For IO there is no easy way to predict the best DOP. For example, magnetic disks like DOP 1. SSDs like 4-16(?). Web services could like pretty much any value. I could continue this list for dozens more factors including databases, lock contention etc.

You need to test different amounts in a testing environment. Then, use the best performing value.

Using `Environment.ProcessorCount` makes no sense with IO. When you add CPUs IO does not get faster.

Comment: Your argument against using it for IO makes sense. But why (specifically) is `Parallel` or `PLINQ` better off than this extension using `async-await`?

Comment: I think they have a different approach to spawning thread. This code would always spawn N while Parallel has provisions to spawn less if the thread pool is saturated. Not sure it matters much, though. In any case async is pointless with CPU bound work.

Comment: As I read your responses it seems like common sense. Thank you for explaining the use cases for each type of problem: CPU vs. IO vs. External(think HTTP requests).

Answer (score 1):

Starting from .NET 6, the [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) method is now part of the standard libraries. The default [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism) for this method is [`Environment.ProcessorCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.processorcount). This doesn't mean that the number of CPU cores is the optimal concurrency limit for the majority of asynchronous scenarios. It only means that *any* positive number is preferable to `-1` (unlimited), which is the default `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` for the non-asynchronous [`Parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel) APIs. An unlimited default parallelism would cause lots of unintentional DoS attacks, by developers who would just experiment with the API. Selecting a constant value, like `10`, was probably deemed too arbitrary, so they opted for the `Environment.ProcessorCount`. It makes sense. It is logical to assume that there is some correlation between the power of the machine, and the power of the network that is connected to.

My suggestion for configuring the `Parallel.ForEachAsync`/`MaxDegreeOfParallelism` is to not rely on the default, experiment with various values, start with a small value like `2`, be conservative, and consider making it configurable manually through the App.config. The optimal value might change during the lifetime of the application.

It should be noted that the .NET 6 `Parallel.ForEachAsync` method has not identical behavior with the one-liner `ForEachAsync` that is  shown in the question. The most important difference is that in case of an exception the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` will stop invoking the `body`, and will complete ASAP as faulted. On the contrary the one-liner will continue invoking the `body`, as long as there is a worker task still alive. Each error will kill one of the `dop` workers. If you are unlucky to have exactly `dop - 1` early exceptions, the last standing worker will slowly process the remaining elements alone, until the exceptions are finally surfaced. For implementations with better behavior on .NET platforms older than .NET 6, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136542/parallel-foreach-with-asynchronous-lambda) question, or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallel-foreach).

Answer (score -1):

Values of DOP affect the hardware. You can give any feasible value to DOP.

The values you give that much parallel code process at a time.

For example, If you have DataSet having 1000 rows in you need to process each rows and perform certain operation on it. Now if your DOP value is 50 then at a time 50 rows will process in parallel.