# How can I convert this Task.WhenAll() implementation to a Parallel.ForEach()?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I have the code below which checks for user group authorization across domains.  The code checks for authorization using a various combination of domains:

```
//build domain combos for lookup
var domainCombos = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
domainCombos.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("corp-domain-1", "corp-domain-1"));
domainCombos.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("corp-domain-1", "corp-domain-2"));
domainCombos.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("corp-domain-2", "corp-domain-2"));
domainCombos.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("corp-domain-2", "corp-domain-1"));

var results = await Task.WhenAll(domainCombos.Select(domainCombo =>
{
    request.GroupDomainName = domainCombo.Item1;
    request.UserDomainName = domainCombo.Item2;
    return GetSingleAuthorizedGroupInfo(request);
}));
var aggregateResults = results.Where(x => x != null)
    .SelectMany(result => result).ToList();
return aggregateResults;
```

I think that this routine appears to be a good candidate for `Parallel.ForEach` b/c there are no interdependencies between calls to `GetSingleAuthorizedGroupInfo()`.

Also, when I execute with 1 domainCombo, the response returns in 800ms, whereas when I execute with 4 domainCombos the response returns in about 1800ms. How would I go about converting the code above to leverage `Parallel.ForEach`?

Comment: this code already runs parallel, what advantage do you expect to gain from using Parallel.ForEach ?

Comment: Why can't you just use a  loop (for or foreach) do instantiate all the tasks and put them into a task array and then use `Task.WaitAll(taskArr);` ? This will fire `n` threads and your function will return once all tasks are done, but they will be running in parallel.

Comment: @bmvr are there any advantages to Task.WaitAll() over Task.WhenAll()?

Comment: @user9393635 no, but there is a disadvantage of synchronously blocking on async code

Comment: Does your code execute `async` operations? Or is `GetSingleAuthorizedGroupInfo` purely CPU bound? This is the first question you should ask yourself. CPU bound operations are good candidates for parallel work, `async` operations (HTTP requests and IO operations in general), instead, are not, and should be awaited (like you already do).

Comment: @bmvr `Task.WaitAll()` is a synchronization method while `Task.WhenAll()` is an asynchronous method. They are basically the same but you should notice that when you use synchronization waiting for asynchronous methods, you might got dead-block.

Comment: Related: [ForEachAsync with Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907650/foreachasync-with-result).