# WhenAny vs WhenAll vs WaitAll vs none, given that results are being used immediately

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

I have to consume the output of multiple asynchronous tasks right after they complete.

Would there be a reasonable perf difference in any of these approaches?

#### Simple Await

```
public async Task<List<Baz>> MyFunctionAsync(List<Foo> FooList) {
    results = new List<Baz>();
    List<Task<List<Baz>>> tasks = new List<Task<List<Baz>>>();

    foreach (Foo foo in FooList) {
        tasks.Add(FetchBazListFromFoo(entry));

    foreach (Task<List<Baz>> task in tasks) {
        results.AddRange(await task);

    return results;
}
```

#### WhenAll

```
public async Task<List<Baz>> MyFunctionAsync(List<Foo> FooList) {
    results = new List<Baz>();
    List<Task<List<Baz>>> tasks = new List<Task<List<Baz>>>();

    foreach (Foo foo in FooList) {
        tasks.Add(FetchBazListFromFoo(entry));

    foreach (List<Baz> bazList in await Task.WhenAll(tasks))
        results.AddRange(bazList);

    return results;
}
```

#### WaitAll

```
public async Task<List<Baz>> MyFunctionAsync(List<Foo> FooList) {
    results = new List<Baz>();
    List<Task<List<Baz>>> tasks = new List<Task<List<Baz>>>();

    foreach (Foo foo in FooList) {
        tasks.Add(FetchBazListFromFoo(entry));

    foreach (List<Baz> bazList in await Task.WaitAll(tasks))
        results.AddRange(bazList);

    return results;
}
```

#### WhenAny

```
public async Task<List<Baz>> MyFunctionAsync(List<Foo> FooList) {
    results = new List<Baz>();
    List<Task<List<Baz>>> tasks = new List<Task<List<Baz>>>();

    foreach (Foo foo in FooList) {
        tasks.Add(FetchBazListFromFoo(entry));

    while (tasks.Count > 0) {
        Task<List<Baz>> finished = Task.WhenAny(tasks);
        results.AddRange(await finished);
        tasks.Remove(finished);
    }

    return results;
}
```

- `FooList` has about 100 entries.
- `FetchBazListFromFoo` makes about 30 REST API calls and does some synchronous work for each result of REST API call.

---

Additionally, Is there an internal overhead diff in WhenAll v WhenAny?

WhenAll returns control after all tasks are completed, while WhenAny returns control as soon as a single task is completed. The latter seems to require more internal management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple await will perform each item one after another, essentially synchronously - this would be the slowest.

`WhenAll` will wait for all of tasks to be done - the runtime will be whatever the longest single task is.

Do not use `WaitAll` - it is synchronous, just use `WhenAll`

`WhenAny` allows you to handle each task as it completes. This in will be faster than `WhenAll` in some cases, depending on how much processing you have to do after the task.

IMO, unless you need to start post processing immediately when each task complets, `WhenAll` is the simplest/cleanest approach and would work fine in most scenarios.

Comment: shouldn't await return the control to caller once it see a blocking call (in this case the REST API call)? Once the control is returned, the control should proceed to execute other await calls?

Comment: Is there an internal overhead diff in WhenAll v WhenAny? In whenAll control will return after all is done, while in whenany control may return as soon as one is done. The latter seems to require more internal management.

Comment: My assumption is `WhenAny` would end up with more overhead if only slightly, but that would be entirely a guess on my part. The `await` is essentially a stopping point for the code, it will wait until the asynchronous operation is complete before proceeding.

Comment: Depending on how many calls you need ot make, it might be worth looking into [Async Enumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/november/csharp-iterating-with-async-enumerables-in-csharp-8). It would make sense to leverage `WhanAny` with this.

Comment: WhenAll does not start tasks, as tasks are usually already running – here FetchBazListFromFoo. It merely wait until the tasks complete. This means that even with the simple await all tasks are running concurrently, because the tasks where created without waiting for one to finish. The only difference between consecutively await each task and using Task.WhenAll is in case an exception occurs, where WhenAll will still wait for everyone to complete, which is not the case for the simple awaits.

Comment: If the results are to be used immediately, Microsoft has a helpful blog post that is recommending the WhenAny approach with a while loop: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/start-multiple-async-tasks-and-process-them-as-they-complete

Answer (score 9):

The third approach (WaitAll) is invalid because the [`Task.WaitAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall) is a `void` returning method, so it cannot be awaited. This code will just produce a compile-time error.

The other three approaches are very similar, with some subtle differences.

**Simple Await:** starts all tasks and then awaits them one-by-one. It will collect all results in the correct order. In case of an exception it will return before all tasks are completed, and it will report only the exception of the first failed task (first in order, not chronologically).
Not recommended unless this behavior is exactly what you want (most likely it isn't).

**WhenAll**: starts all tasks and then awaits all of them to complete. It will collect all results in the correct order. In case of an exception it will return after all tasks have been completed, and it will report only the exception of the first failed task (first in order, not chronologically¹).
Not recommended unless this behavior is exactly what you want (most likely it isn't either).

**WhenAny**: starts all tasks and then awaits all of them to complete. It will collect all results in order of completion, so the original order will not be preserved. In case of an exception it will return immediately, and it will report the exception of the first failed task (this time first chronologically, not in order). The `while` loop introduces an overhead that is absent from the other two approaches, which will be quite significant if the number of tasks is larger than 10,000, and it will grow exponentially as the number of tasks becomes larger.
Not recommended unless this behavior is exactly what you want (I bet that by now you aren't a fan of this either).

**All of these approaches**: will bombard the remote server with a huge number of concurrent requests, making it hard for that machine to respond quickly, and in the worst case triggering a defensive anti-DOS-attack mechanism.

A better solution to this problem is to use the specialized API [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync), available from .NET 6 and later. This method parallelizes multiple asynchronous operations, enforces a maximum
degree of parallelism which by default is `Environment.ProcessorCount`, and also supports cancellation and fast completion in case of exceptions. You can find a usage example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136542/parallel-foreach-with-asynchronous-lambda/68901782#68901782). This method does not return the results of the asynchronous operations. You can collect the results as a side effect of the asynchronous operations, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907650/foreachasync-with-result/71129678#71129678) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400133/when-to-use-blockingcollection-and-when-concurrentbag-instead-of-listt/64823123#64823123).

¹ <sub>The order of the `Task.WhenAll` exceptions changed in .NET 8. For details see [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/93504) GitHub issue, which is currently unresolved (March 2024).</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do have an agreement with the server and am sure that the job will not be throttled. Will definitely look into TPL.

Comment: Await, WhenAll, WhenAny do not start tasks. Tasks usually start hot (the only case when a task is not running is when he was created with `new Task` which however is not the recommended way of creating tasks). Await, WhenAll, WhenAny simply wait until one or more tasks have completed.

Comment: @ckuri I am referring to the approaches that the OP named "Simple Await", "WhenAll" and "WhenAny". I am not referring to the keyword/methods `await`, `Task.WhenAll` and `Task.WhenAny` per se. These approaches include the creation of the (presumably hot) tasks, as you can see in the embedded in the question code.

Comment: I think the first sentence of **WhenAny** should be: starts all tasks and then awaits *any* of them to complete. Looks like a copy-paste error.

Comment: @​MustafaÖzçetin the *"WhenAny"* in my answer does not correspond to the [`Task.WhenAny`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany) method. It corresponds to the fourth approach inside the body of the question, titled **WhenAny** (in bold type).