# Run multiple WebRequest in parallel in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, parallel-processing, request

I have the following situation. I want to execute 6 URL request (each request is with different auth_token and returns different data ). Here is the function that is making requests for different auth_token.

```
 private static async Task<List<Positions>> GeneratePositions(string auth_token)
        {
            var request = WebRequest.Create(www.some_url.com);

            request.Headers.Add("authorization", "Bearer " + auth_token);
            request.Method = "GET";

            WebResponse response = null;

            try
            {
                response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // TODO log
                throw ex;
            }

            var dataStreamRes = response.GetResponseStream();
            var reader = new StreamReader(dataStreamRes);
            var buffResponse = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

            var positions = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Positions>>(buffResponse);

            reader.Close();
            dataStreamRes.Close();
            response.Close();

            return positions;
        }
```

This function is ran using `await`  operator. But the problem is that every requests waits for the previous one to start.
Do you have any idea how I can run multiple requests for multiple auth_tokens at the same time, without waiting the previous one to finish, and of course collect the data returned.

Comment: hmm, maybe problem is in the place where you call your function ?

Comment: Might be helpful: [ForEachAsync with Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907650/foreachasync-with-result)

Answer (score 0):

The position to make it parallel is not inside the method you've shown, but where you'd call it.

Instead of calling this method like:

```
// for example sequential:
foreach(var siteInfo in siteInfoList)
{
    // await per call.
    var positions = await GeneratePositions(siteInfo.url, siteInfo.auth_token);

    foreach(var position in positions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(position.XXX);
    }
}
```

You can use the [Task.WhenAll()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-6.0) method. This might run the tasks parallel.

```
// create a list of tasks
var tasks = new List<Task<List<Positions>>>();

foreach(var siteInfo in siteInfoList)
{
    // add the task to a list of tasks
    tasks.Add(GeneratePositions(siteInfo.url, siteInfo.auth_token));
}

// await them all.
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

// read back the results.
foreach(var task in tasks)
{
    foreach(var position in task.Result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(position.XXX);
    }
}
```

A big difference between these two options is exception handling.

Comment: Okay, but how can I accumulate the returned List<Positions> with this approach ?

Comment: Each `Task` has a result: `task.Result` in the example.