# Destination array was not long enough. when when using Task.WhenAll and AddRange responses to a list

Tags: c#, linq, async-await, .net-core-3.1

I'm using `Task.WhenAll` to call multiple async requests with different parameters to get `patients` of various `pharmacies` by selecting patient ids of that pharmacy.
And I want to add this data to one list and then map it to other models.

Here is my code.

```
var patients = new List<PatientDTO>();
            await Task.WhenAll(
                pharmacyIds.Select(async pharmacyId =>
                    patients.AddRange(await _patientService.GetPatientsByClientIds(pharmacyId, recipes
                            .Where(x => x.PharmacyId == pharmacyId)
                            .Select(x => x.PatientId)))));
```

I'm getting this data paginated in my request, and my page size is often 50
most of the time, this works correctly, but sometimes it throws an exception with the message:
`Destination array was not long enough. Check the destination index, length, and the array's lower bounds. (Parameter 'destinationArray')`.

Here is some more information about the exception.

```
at System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Int32 sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, Int32 destinationIndex, Int32 length, Boolean reliable)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Insert(Int32 index, T item)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at Coach.Domain.Queries.GetRecipeLogsQueryHandler.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<<Handle>b__14>d.MoveNext()
```

Where is my mistake, and how can I solve this?

- **NOTE: I want multiple requests to be async, and I don't want to call them in sequence.**

Comment: Don't use such code in the first place. Don't try to modify a `List` from multiple threads and *definitely* don't try to use `Select` to cause side-effects. That's at least two critical bugs. Whatever you're trying to do there are better ways

Comment: Looks like the exception is originating from `Coach.Domain.Queries.GetRecipeLogsQueryHandler`. Is there some relevant code that gets the `recipes` parameter missing here?

Comment: Don't try to reduce multiple complex operations in a single call either. Method chaining is nice up to a point. In this case though, it results in hard-to read code (where does LINQ end and the HTTP call start?) and makes it a lot harder to debug and add the inevitable error handling and retry code necessary in all remote calls

Comment: @BarryO'Kane the error is caused because multiple threads are trying to modify the same, thread-unsafe `List<>`

Comment: I think your code can overlap since you are writing all your patients to one single array from multiple threads. I suppose this creates the possibility of adding to a list that is currently being modified. I would suggest to get all the objects separately first and after all of them have been completed add them to the list.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane not at all it's working most of the time and the recipes parameter is a list  gotten from the database

Comment: Thank you, @PanagiotisKanavos , for your clear reply. I will Edit my code and post.

Comment: If you want to call `_patientService.GetPatientsByClientIds` concurrently, you have to ensure that service is thread safe. If not - create new service for each request.

Answer (score 2):

If you can change `GetPatientsAsync` having a version of `GetPatientsAsync` that takes a collection of `(pharmacyId, recipes)` and returns the patient ids should be significantly more performant than paralleling the requests to `GetOne`.

This would be a difference between a single query vs multiple trips to the database and having a single query would be much faster.

```
Task<List<int>> GetPatientsAsync(
   IEnumerable<(string pharmancyId, IEnumerable<Prescription> prescriptions)> inputs)

//Or (because prescriptions don't seem to change in your "loop")
Task<List<int>> GetPatientsAsync(
   IEnumerable<string> pharmancyIds, IEnumerable<Prescription> prescriptions)
```

##### Other secondary points

- GetPatientsByClientIds has `ByClientIds` but doesn't take in client ids
- GetPatientsXXX should be GetPatientsAsync (suffix)
- If you have to `.Where(x => x.PharmacyId == pharmacyId)` after calling
  `GetPatientsByClientIds(pharmacyId, recipes))` - which takes `pharmacyId` - seems  to suggest that something is not right.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving the `patients` as a side-effect of the `Select` lambda execution is not a good idea, because it makes your program fragile and difficult to understand. If you insist at doing it, you should at least protect the mutation of the `patients` list with a [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement):

```
var patients = new List<PatientDTO>();
await Task.WhenAll(
    pharmacyIds.Select(async pharmacyId =>
    {
        var sublist = (await _patientService.GetPatientsByClientIds(pharmacyId, recipes))
                .Where(x => x.PharmacyId == pharmacyId)
                .Select(x => x.PatientId)
                .ToList();
        lock (patients) patients.AddRange(sublist);
    }));
```

It is important to release the `lock` as soon as possible, so the `sublist` must be a materialized collection (`List<T>`, array etc). Otherwise, if it's a non-materialized enumerable, the `AddRange` will have to do a lot of work, it'll take a lot of time, harming your goal to parallelize the operations.

A better approach is to remove the side-effects, and merge the patients after the completion of all the tasks. Example:

```
Task<List<int>>[] tasks = pharmacyIds
    .Select(async pharmacyId =>
    {
        return (await _patientService.GetPatientsByClientIds(pharmacyId, recipes))
            .Where(x => x.PharmacyId == pharmacyId)
            .Select(x => x.PatientId)
            .ToList();
    }).ToArray();

List<int>[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

List<int> patients = results.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

An even better approach IMHO is to switch from the `Task.WhenAll` to the new (.NET 6) [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) API, because it allows you to configure the degree of parallelism. It has the disadvantage that it doesn't propagate the results (workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907650/foreachasync-with-result/71129678#71129678)), so you'll have to use the `lock`+`AddRange` technique from the first example, or a concurrent collection like the `ConcurrentQueue<T>`.