# Inconsistent outcome when trying to fetch all items from a paginated url

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, pagination, dotnet-httpclient

I am having the issue of fetching all forms currently hosted in hubspot.

I tried with a simple for loop where I made one request at the time, and fetched one form at a time, which worked, but was very slow.

I then thought it might work better if I created a seperate task for each request, and then made the task create each request, and store them in one common list.

Problem is that I expect the list to have 2000 items, but I never seem to get that, it seem pretty inconsistent the number of items I get?

But how come?

This is how I have setup my for fetching scheme.

```
private static async Task<IEnumerable<HubspotModel>> GetForms(
    string hubspotPath, int pageSize)
{
    int totalResults;
    int offset = 0;
    List<HubspotModel> output = new();
    List<Task> tasks = new();
    using var client = new HttpClient();
    {
        System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpResponseHeaders requestHeader = client
            .GetAsync($"https://api.hubapi.com{hubspotPath}?" +
                $"hapikey={HubspotConfiguration.ApiKey}&limit={1}&offset={0}")
            .Result.Headers;
        totalResults = int.Parse(requestHeader.GetValues("x-total-count").First());
        do
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
            {
                int scopedOffset = offset;
                IEnumerable<HubspotModel> forms = GetFormsFromHubspot(hubspotPath,
                    pageSize, offset, client);
                output.AddRange(forms);

            }).ContinueWith(requestReponse =>
            {
                if (requestReponse.IsFaulted)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("it failed");
                }
            }));
            offset += pageSize;
        }
        while (totalResults > offset);

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    return output;
}

private static IEnumerable<HubspotModel> GetFormsFromHubspot(string hubspotPath,
    int pageSize, int offset, HttpClient client)
{
    HttpResponseMessage request = client
        .GetAsync($"https://api.hubapi.com{hubspotPath}?" +
            $"hapikey={HubspotConfiguration.ApiKey}&limit={pageSize}&offset={offset}")
        .Result;
    request.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string content = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> jsonResponse = JsonSerializer
        .Deserialize<IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>>(content,
        new JsonSerializerOptions() { });
    var guid = Guid.Parse(jsonResponse.First()["guid"].ToString());
    var forms = jsonResponse.Select(x => new HubspotModel()
    {
        id = Guid.Parse(x["guid"].ToString()),
        FormName = x["name"].ToString(),
        Form = x
    });
    return forms;
}
```

Comment: Please do NOT use .Result on a Task, please prefer await

Comment: You can use IAsyncEnumerable, Channels and HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync to simplify your code *a lot*. There's no reason to use tasks and ContinueWith directly

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'd suggest to make `GetFormsFromHotspot` an `async` as well and use `await client.GetAsync( ...)` and `await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` instead of `client.GetAsync(...).Result` and `ReadAsStringAsync().Result` respectively, because using `.Result` will block the current thread and thus, you will throw away the advantages of async Tasks.

But the main cause of the problem should be the following

```
GetFormsFromHubspot(hubspotPath, pageSize, offset, client);
```

Here you are calling the `GetFormsFromHubspot` with an `offset` parameter from an outer scope (and that value keeps changing), thus it will not use the value it had when you created that task but it uses the value it actually has, when that particular part of the code is really executed. So the value that is used as an offset is quite random. You already tried to create a

```
int scopedOffset = offset;
```

but you don't use it. And also you create it at the wrong position. Create that `scopedOffset` *outside*  of the task, but *inside*  the loop's body. So it will be created at the creationtime of the task. And because it's inside the loop's body, a new value will be created for each task.

The following should do the trick (after you refactor `GetFormsFromHubspot` to be async.

```
do {
  int scopedOffset = offset
  tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => {
      IEnumerable<HubspotModel> forms = await GetFormsFromHubspot(hubspotPath, pageSize, scopedOffset, client);
      output.AddRange(forms);
    })     
    .ContinueWith(...);
  );
  offset += pageSize;
} while (totalResults > offset);
```

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with your code is that the `List<T>` is not thread-safe. When multiple threads are `Add`ing to a list concurrently without synchronization, its behavior becomes undefined (throws exceptions, becomes corrupted etc). There are many ways to solve this problem:

1. Synchronize the access to the list with the [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) statement: `lock (output) output.AddRange(forms);`.
2. Use a [concurrent collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/) instead of the `List<T>`, for example a [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1).
3. Avoid collecting manually the output altogether. Instead of storing your tasks in a `List<Task>`, you can store them in a `List<Task<HubspotModel[]>>`, meaning that each task will be a generic [`Task<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1), with the `TResult` being an array of `HubspotModel` instances. Finally you will get all the output at once, when you `await` the [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall).

Below is an implementation of the third idea. Notice that I have avoided creating a `HttpClient` instance, because [the recommendation is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#create-and-initialize-httpclient) to instantiated this class only once, and reuse it throughout the life of the application.

```
private static async Task<HubspotModel[]> GetFormsAsync(HttpClient client,
    string hubspotPath, int pageSize)
{
    string url = $"https://api.hubapi.com{hubspotPath}?hapikey=" +
        $"{HubspotConfiguration.ApiKey}&limit={1}&offset={0}";
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    int totalCount = Int32.Parse(response.Headers
        .GetValues("x-total-count").First());

    List<int> offsets = new();
    for (int offset = 0; offset < totalCount; offset += pageSize)
        offsets.Add(offset);

    Task<HubspotModel[]>[] tasks = offsets.Select(offset => Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        HubspotModel[] forms = await GetFormsAsync(client,
            hubspotPath, pageSize, offset).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return forms;
    })).ToArray();

    HubspotModel[][] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return results.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
}

private async static Task<HubspotModel[]> GetFormsAsync(HttpClient client,
    string hubspotPath, int pageSize, int offset)
{
    string url = $"https://api.hubapi.com{hubspotPath}?hapikey=" +
        $"{HubspotConfiguration.ApiKey}&limit={pageSize}&offset={offset}";
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
    IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> jsonResponse = JsonSerializer
        .Deserialize<IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>>(content,
        new JsonSerializerOptions() { });

    Guid guid = Guid.Parse(jsonResponse.First()["guid"].ToString());
    HubspotModel[] forms = jsonResponse.Select(x => new HubspotModel()
    {
        Id = Guid.Parse(x["guid"].ToString()),
        FormName = x["name"].ToString(),
        Form = x
    }).ToArray();
    return forms;
}
```

One more improvement that you could consider doing is to switch from the `Task.WhenAll` to the new (.NET 6) API [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync). The advantage is that you'll get control over the degree of parallelism, and so you'll be able to reduce the parallelization in case the remote server can't keep up with the pressure. Unfortunatelly the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` method does not return the results like the `Task.WhenAll`, so you'll be back to your original problem. You can find a solution about this here: [ForEachAsync with Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907650/foreachasync-with-result).

Comment: The last line 
    return results.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
seems a bit redundant, why not just return     return results.SelectMany(x => x)?

Comment: Because a return type `Task<HubspotModel[]>` conveys stronger guarantees than a `Task<IEnumerable<HubspotModel>>`. In the first case you know that you have a materialized collection that can be enumerated cheaply any number of times, that getting the number of elements in the collection is cheap etc. In the second case you get a sequence that might be deferred (or not), that enumerating it might involve heavy background processing, and enumerating it multiple times might induce this cost multiple times. A `Task` is already something lazy, so having a deferred `TResult` doesn't make much sense.