# Parallel.ForEachAsync keep sort order

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreachasync

I am trying to execute file upload using `Parallel.ForEachAsync`, it works but loses the sort order. Is there any method to synchronize sort order or source and destination lists?

```
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(model.DestinationFiles,
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20 }, async (file, CancellationToken) =>
    {
        var storeAsync = await _fileServerService.Init(displayUrl).StoreAsync(file.FileInfo, false, file.OutputFileName);
        convertResultDto.Files.Add(new ConverterConvertResultFile(storeAsync));
    });
```

Previously I used Linq parallel operator (PLINQ), which has the `AsOrdered` operator to deal with sorting. Anyway, I think the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` is better for using in async methods with I/O scenario?

```
var storeFiles = model.DestinationFiles.AsParallel().AsOrdered().WithDegreeOfParallelism(50)
    .Select(file => StoreAsync(file.FileInfo, false, file.OutputFileName).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
    .Select(storeFile => new StoreFile
    {
        FileId = storeFile.FileId,
        Url = storeFile.Url,
        OutputFileName = storeFile.OutputFileName,
        Size = storeFile.Size
    });
```

Comment: Related: [ForEachAsync with Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907650/foreachasync-with-result)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you're wanting to get a set of results and store them in a resulting collection. `Parallel` is designed for more operations *without* results. For operations with results, you can use PLINQ for CPU-bound operations or asynchronous concurrency for I/O-bound operations. Unfortunately, there isn't a PLINQ equivalent for `Parallel.ForEachAsync`, which would be the closest equivalent to your current code.

Asynchronous concurrency uses `Task.WhenAll` to get the results of multiple asynchronous operations. It can also use `SemaphoreSlim` for throttling. Something like this:

```
var mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(20);
var results = await Task.WhenAll(model.DestinationFiles.Select(async file =>
{
  await mutex.WaitAsync();
  try
  {
    var storeAsync = await _fileServerService.Init(displayUrl).StoreAsync(file.FileInfo, false, file.OutputFileName);
    return new ConverterConvertResultFile(storeAsync);
  }
  finally { mutex.Release(); }
});
convertResultDto.Files.AddRange(results);
```

However, if you have a mixture of CPU-bound and I/O-bound operations, then you'll probably want to continue to use `ForEachAsync`. In that case, you can create the entries in your destination collection first, then perform each operation with an index so it knows where to store them:

```
// This code assumes convertResultDto.Files is empty at this point.
var count = model.DestinationFiles.Count;
convertResultDto.Files.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat<ConverterConvertResultFile>(null!, count));
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(
    model.DestinationFiles.Select((file, i) => (file, i)),
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20 },
    async item =>
    {
      var (file, i) = item;
      var storeAsync = await _fileServerService.Init(displayUrl).StoreAsync(file.FileInfo, false, file.OutputFileName);
      convertResultDto.Files[i] = new ConverterConvertResultFile(storeAsync);
    });
```

Comment: The `SemaphoreSlim`+`Task.WhenAll` solution has the issue that it doesn't complete early in case of an exception. In case you have 1,000 items to process and the first item fails, the rest 999 items will still be processed, only for getting the same exception at the end.

Comment: Does `ForEachAsync` complete early in case of exception?

Comment: Yep. It also cancels the `CancellationToken` that is passed to the `body`, for extra fast completion.