# Calling a rest API using Tasks in loop and achieve good performance

Tags: c#, performance, asynchronous, concurrency, .net-4.6.1

I have a file with around 8000 employee records that I need to process by calling an rest API for each record. The sequential API calls are taking a lot of time, so I want to call them asynchronously in tasks and wait for all tasks to finish. I plan to have three tasks running at a time.

I have written the following code, but I'm concerned about race conditions or multi-threading problems since I am updating the employee entity inside the task. My understanding is I can update the entities but cannot call dbcontext methods. I know that the DBContext is not thread safe, so I am calling `SaveChanges` outside of the task loop. Can anyone review my code and let me know if I'm doing it right? Here's my pseudo code:

```
private async TempMethod()
{
    var dbcontext = new DBContext();
    var employees = dbcontext.Employees.ToList();

    var allTasks = new List<Task<APIResult>();

    var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: 3);

    foreach (var employee in employees)
    {
        await throttler.WaitAsync();
        allTasks.Add(
                       Task.Run(async () =>
                       {
                           try
                           {
                               var apiResult = await apiClient.Update(employee);
                               if (apiResult == "Success")
                               {
                                   employee.lastupdatedby = "Importer";
                               }

                               apiResult.recordNumber = employee.recordNumber;
                               return apiResult;
                           }
                           finally
                           {
                                   throttler.Release();
                           }
                       }
                       );
    }

    var results = await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        dbcontext.APIResults.Add(result);
    }

    //Save both Updated Employee and the Result entitities.
    dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: I don't see a wait call on the semaphore. Only release?

Comment: And i think, I just would split the input collection in 3 parts and have 3 concurrently running tasks sequentially make the calls each for one of those partitions...

Comment: likmiting to three like that is not good, you are going to get a large number of threads stalled waiting on that semaphore. I would use ParallelForEAch with a limit of 3

Comment: @Fildor I added the wait on the semaphore now. It was just a pseudo code. Any concern on updating the employee entity inside the task. There won't be any multi-threading issue here right?

Comment: Not 100% sure. But that should be easily testable.

Comment: @pm100 "If the work you have is I/O-bound, use async and await without Task.Run. You should not use the Task Parallel Library." I saw this here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios

Comment: The last part about TPL may be in parts outdated in newer versions of dotnet.

Comment: I could also imagine a solution with an ActionBlock from DataFlow which is technically also TPL.

Comment: It maybe also worthwhile to investigate if the API offers bulk or batch endpoints, so you can reduce the number of calls.

Comment: What .NET platform are you targeting? .NET 7?

Comment: If you are targeting .net 6.0 or higher you can use `Parallel.ForEachAsync` see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync?view=net-7.0) it also supports limiting max concurrency

Comment: Unfortunately  this  code is targeted for .Net 4.6.1 and the API I’m using doesn’t offer batch calls.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems right to me, under these conditions:

1. The `employee.lastupdatedby` and `apiResult.recordNumber` are either public fields, or trivial properties backed by private fields (without side-effects).
2. The class of which the `apiClient` is an instance, is thread-safe.
3. You want to process all the `employees` anyway, even in case of an early exception. In other words you don't want to complete ASAP in case of errors.
4. In case of an exception you are OK with only a part of the `employees` having their `lastupdatedby` updated.
5. In case of multiple exceptions you are OK with propagating only one of the exceptions (the exception of the first `employee` in the `employees` list that failed).

As a side note, personally I would prefer to abstract the parallelization/throttling functionality in a separate helper method, instead of mixing threading and TPL mechanisms with my application code. I would like to link to a good quality implementation of a `ForEachAsync` that returns results, and is compatible with .NET 4.6.1, but I can't find any. Jon Skeet's implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907650/foreachasync-with-result/30907870#30907870) is decent, but it doesn't have ideal behavior in case of exceptions, and it doesn't preserve the order of the results.