# Async method getting called second time by another thread

Tags: c#, async-await, concurrency, task-parallel-library, webapi

I'm making a call to an endpoint like below which pulls data from a proprietary API that we are using.

I'm making parallel calls in `Sync2` method to get order details. As their API is returning a 429, we are delaying for some time and then making the call again. (I know this is pretty basic and we might have to go for exponential delay. But we're getting there.). And I'm sending live updates of this process using SignalR.

**Problem:** The `Provider.Sync` method is being called again by another thread while `Sync2` is method is still executing. `Sync2` has to bring data for around 400 orders. So, we have to make 400 API calls. I'm making concurrent calls in chunks of 5. We also have an `OnExecutingAsync` filter and even that method is getting called when I inspected the App Insights logs. **I cannot figure out what I'm missing here and why the control is again going back and executing the same method.**

I'm not calling this endpoint again from UI. Appreciate any guidance I could get. Thanks in advance

Edit: This issue is only happening on cloud instances but not in local.

```
[HttpGet("orders/sync")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Sync()
{
    var result = await Provider.Sync();
    return Ok(result);
}


public static class Provider {

    public static async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Sync() {
        var result = await Sync1();
        await _hubcontext.Clients.Group($"user").SendAsync("liveUpdates", new SyncProgress("Sync1 complete.", 50));
        if(result){
            var orderDetails = await Sync2(); // This has to bring data for around 400 orders. So, we have to make 400 API calls. I'm making concurrent calls in chunks of 5.
        await _hubcontext.Clients.Group($"user").SendAsync("liveUpdates", new SyncProgress("Sync2 complete.", 100));
            return orderDetails;
        }
        
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>()
    }

    private static async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Sync2() {

        List<string> orders = new List<string> {"12345", "23456", "12345", "23456", "12345", "23456"};
        var tasks = orders.Select(order => ApiClient.GetAsync($"/v1/orders/{order}", "xddsw")); //GetAsync returns a Task and I'm awaiting on the result from the endpoint that I'm calling.
        var responses = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

}

public async static Task<T?> GetAsync<T>(string apiUrl, string accessToken = "", RestRequest request = default, int retryOption = 0)
{
    request ??= new RestRequest(apiUrl);

    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
    {
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");
    }

    var response = await ApiClient.ExecuteGetAsync(request);
    if (!response.IsSuccessful)
    {
        var statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
        if (statusCode == StatusCodes.Status429TooManyRequests)
        {
            if (retryOption > 3)
                throw new Exception("TooMany Requests. Please try aftersome time", statusCode);
            await Task.Delay(60000);
            return await GetAsync<T>(apiUrl, accessToken, retryOption: ++retryOption);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(response.Content, statusCode);
        }
    }

    return response.Content.Length > 2 ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content) : default;
}
```

Comment: ​As a side note, have you considered using the [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) API instead of the improvised "make concurrent calls in chunks of 5" approach? For a variant that returns results see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907650/foreachasync-with-result).

Comment: What `MasterSync` method are you referring to?

Comment: If you're saying the `/orders/sync` endpoint is getting hit a second time, that has nothing to do with any of the code you've provided. The client is probably hitting your endpoint a second time, and you haven't shared any details about the client calling this endpoint.

Comment: Hi @StriplingWarrior. Apologies for the typo. I have edited the question. I was referring to the Sync method in Provider class. I checked the network on my client, but there is no record of another API call for this endpoint.

Comment: Hi @TheodorZoulias. No, I did not. I will give it a try. But I might still run into the same problem as I would be making 300-400 calls in parallel and some of them might return 429 and would potentially be delayed.

Comment: Yep, I don't expect that switching to the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` will solve the problem, but it might help you indirectly by simplifying the code. It is easier to find bugs when the code is simple.

Comment: It's not really possible to help with the data you've provided. If `Provider.Sync` is getting executed again, it's because something is calling it again. Maybe there's another action in your code base that invokes it? Or maybe there's another client instance somewhere that's invoking your action a second time. You may need more logging to narrow things down. If you're using Application Insights, check how the Requests, Dependencies, and Traces are interacting for a given OperationId.

Answer (score -1):

How long is it taking to process a request?  I don't know what's calling that GET method, but is there a chance it has a retry policy?

The default http timeout is probably about 100 seconds. Your inner retry has a delay of 60 seconds.

So imagine someone calling your http method. GetAsync gets a 429, waits 60 secs for a retry... how long is the original caller now waiting? Another retry, perhaps... the caller is going to timeout before your function thinks it is done.

A http call to a service that then has retries against another service etc... it can lead to long timeouts for the root client.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Pete. I'm making calls from a React application. There is no retry policy either on client side or on server side. The client is failing after 7.5 mins with a Gateway timeout