# How to wait for tasks of varying types?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I am trying to asynchronously complete four tasks and when they are all complete, append them to an object and return it.

Here is my code:

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[4];
tasks[0] = wtData.GetHFServiceData(wtTransfreeeId);
tasks[1] = wtData.GetTLServicesData(wtTransfreeeId);
tasks[2] = wtData.GetHMAServiceData(wtTransfreeeId);
tasks[3] = wtData.GetHSServiceData(wtTransfreeeId);

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

The problem is, since `Task[]` has no Result method, I have to define a type like `Task<MyType>[]`.  But, each of the four tasks above return a different type.

How can I wait until all tasks are complete before adding them to my combined object and returning it?

Comment: Are you looking for `(tasks[0] as Task<MyType>).Result` ?

Comment: Possibly, I will have to try that next.  Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Awaiting multiple Tasks with different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197699/awaiting-multiple-tasks-with-different-results). Also maybe this: [Avoid checking condition twice when assigning from task awaited with Task.WhenAll()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69416885/avoid-checking-condition-twice-when-assigning-from-task-awaited-with-task-whenal).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to store them as `Task<T>` before you put them into an array.

```
Task<YourType1> task1 = wtData.GetHFServiceData(wtTransfreeeId);
Task<YourType2> task2 = wtData.GetTLServicesData(wtTransfreeeId);
...
Task[] tasks = new Task[]{task1, task2, ...};
Task.WaitAll(tasks);

var result1 = task1.Result;//Access the individual task's Result here
...
```

Avoid blocking wait, consider using `Task.WhenAll` with `await` if you're in .Net 4.5. otherwise `Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll` is another option.

Comment: Thanks, seems to work.  Is there a way to do this inline like `Task[] tasks = new Task[] { (Task<List<HFData>>)wtData.GetHFServiceData(wtTransfreeeId) };`?  I tried that but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the return type of `GetHFServiceData`? What error you get?

Comment: The return type is `Task<List<HFData>>` and the error is when I try to access the result by using `tasks[0].Result` is says that Task[] has no such method.

Comment: No, if they are different types you can't do that. You'll have to declare separate variables as I shown you.

Comment: You should be able to put them into the array just fine, since they have a common base type.  Fetching the `Result` property requires the specific type, though.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party as always... I'm currently using this extension method

```cs
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static async Task<(T1, T2)> WhenAll<T1, T2>(this (Task<T1> , Task<T2>) tasks )
        where T1 : class 
        where T2 : class 
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks.Item1, tasks.Item2);
        return (tasks.Item1.Result, tasks.Item2.Result);
    }
}
```

```cs
var (response1, response2)
    = await (_service1.GetTheThing(), _service2.GetTheOtherThing())
    .WhenAll();
```

Would need more methods for running more than 2 async calls