# Better way to collect results from async tasks

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

My MVC app ocasionally results in a deadlock. I think it is likely due to a faulty way I am collecting data from completed async tasks.

I have two independent async methods.

```
var task1 = GetNamesFromSource1Async(); // a database call, may throw an exception
var task2 = GetNamesFromSource2Async(); // a database call, may throw an exception

var total = new List<string>();

await Task.WhenAll(task1, taks2).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

**Question part 1:** What is the safest recommended way and the best practice to collect results from these tasks:

```
// here I already know that both tasks are completed and 
// I am using (or abusing?) await to get task results
List<string> names1 = await task1.ConfigureAwait(false);
List<string> names2 = await task2.ConfigureAwait(false);

if (names1 != null) total.AddRange(names1);
if (names2 != null) total.AddRange(names2);
```

or

```
total.AddRange(task1.IsFaulted ? new List<string> : task1.Result);
total.AddRange(task2.IsFaulted ? new List<string> : task2.Result);
```

?

**Question part 2:** in addition if I want to transform data from the first source, is it safe to use ContinueWith (when I say safe I mean from the standpoint of deadlocks)

```
var task1 = GetNamesFromSource1Async().ContinueWith(t => 
 {
   if ( !t.IsFaulted && t.Result != null)
   {
      return t.Result.Take(1).ToList();
   }
 });
```

**Remark:** here I am trying control for exceptions within each of the tasks by checking IsFaulted flag.

A recommendation on the best practice to solve this problem would be highly appreciated.  I am using .NET 4.5

Answer (score 4):

`.Result` is a blocking call and can lead to deadlock when mixed with async/await

```
var task1 = GetNamesFromSource1Async(); // a database call, may throw an exception
var task2 = GetNamesFromSource2Async(); // a database call, may throw an exception

var total = new List<string>();

var results = await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

total.AddRange(results.Where(s => s != null && s.Count > 0).SelectMany(s => s));
```

**Update**

The above assumed the return types were all the same.

However from your comment...

> How would you modify the last line if I still need to collect results
>   but task1 and task2 are based on different types?

and referencing this answer

[Awaiting multiple Tasks with different results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17197786/5233410)

Then it would be modified as

```
var task1 = GetNamesFromSource1Async(); // a database call, may throw an exception
var task2 = GetNamesFromSource2Async(); // a database call, may throw an exception

var total = new List<string>();

await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

List<String> names1 = await task1;
List<int> names2 = await task2;

//...process results
```

Comment: great answer, thank you. How would you modify the last line if I still need to collect results but task1 and task2 are based on different types? Say task1 is Task<List<String>> but task2 is Task<List<int>> ?

Comment: Do a projection in the SelectMany that returns a common type.

Comment: Found answer actually : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197699/awaiting-multiple-tasks-with-different-results identical what I have been doing with await

Comment: The question only ever used `Result` on an already completed `Task`, and as such wouldn't result in a blocking operation.