# Awaiting tasks of different types

Tags: c#, async-await

```
IEnumerable<Task<Request>> requestTasks = CreateRequestTasks();
Task<Trace> traceTask = CreateTraceTask();

var tasks = new List<Task>();
tasks.AddRange(requestTasks);
tasks.Add(traceTask);

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

How do I get the result from the `requestTasks` collection?

Comment: `foreach(var meTask in tasks) /*get result/*meTask.Result;` ? Or even simplier `foreach(Task<Request> meTask in requestTasks) meTask.Result;`

Comment: @m.rogalski `Result` is a synchronous blocking wait.

Comment: But when you awaited all tasks then the result should be available instantly. At least from what I know.

Comment: @m.rogalski Yes, but the whole point of `async-await` is to not block a thread while you wait for a task to finish.

Comment: I don't understand your point. He's awaiting these tasks here `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` so after these tasks are done he can just use `foreach` to retrieve results ( which were previously made in task ). Or maybe I'm missing something in here.

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17197786/40986 set me in the right direction. But was unsure if using awaiting the task again meant the request is executed again. Appears not to

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Awaiting multiple Tasks with different results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197699/awaiting-multiple-tasks-with-different-results)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How do I get the result from the requestTasks collection?

Keep it as a separate (reified) collection:

```
List<Task<Request>> requestTasks = CreateRequestTasks().ToList();
...
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
var results = await Task.WhenAll(requestTasks);
```

Note that the second `await Task.WhenAll` won't actually do any "asynchronous waiting", because all those tasks are already completed.

Comment: I thought the second await might have caused a second execution of the task. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

Since you have to await them all, you can simply write

```
IEnumerable<Task<Request>> requestTasks = CreateRequestTasks();
Task<Trace> traceTask = CreateTraceTask();

var tasks = await Task.WhenAll(requestTasks);
var trace = await traceTask;
```

inside an equivalent `async` block: it may look clearer imho.

Notice also that the above `traceTask` starts on create (actually this is the [same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17197745/6996876) since the question itself is a duplicate).