# How to assign the results of WaitAll tasks to variables

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a situation like this:

```
var retrievalTasks = new Task[2];

retrievalTasks[0] = GetNodesAsync();

retrievalTasks[1] = GetAssetsToHandleAsync();

Task.WaitAll(retrievalTasks);
```

And I would like the result of `retrievalTasks[0]` and `retrievalTasks[1]` to be stored in variables.

I could achieve this with:

```
 var a = await GetNodesAsync();
 var b = await GetAssetsToHandleAsync();;
```

But I would rather not await both like that, because then they're not fired at the same time right? Or am I misunderstanding?

I've seen this as a reference: [Awaiting multiple Tasks with different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197699/awaiting-multiple-tasks-with-different-results)

But I think this is a slightly different scenario that wouldn't work in my case.

Any ideas?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

```
await Task.WhenAll(catTask, houseTask, carTask);

var cat = await catTask;

var house = await houseTask;

var car = await carTask;
```

This just seemed to wait four times to get the three results. However, @armenm has shown how to avoid that.

Comment: Return type of both the functions should be same.

Comment: What makes you think the one you've found doesn't work in your case?

Comment: Because the answer is waiting all individually, i.e. await a, await b

Comment: which makes me think they won't be fired at the same time

Comment: That's just syntactic stuff at that point, they've been awaited in the `WhenAll`, in practice all the following `awaits` will run synchronously

Comment: so are they awaiting twice in that example, or is it because it's already awaited it won't make a difference?

Comment: Read through the comments etc under the answers - they go into more detail than is worth repeating here.  If you still think it doesn't work for you, please edit your question with reasoning as to why not.

Comment: I read through those comments, but it just looked like it would still be different. Maybe it's just my misunderstanding. However, this answer below is more suited to what I was attempting I think.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here we go, you need to have separate variables for the tasks having respective types:

```
var task1 = GetNodesAsync();
var task2 = GetAssetsToHandleAsync();

Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { task1, task2 });

var result1 = task1.Result;
var result2 = task2.Result;
```

But I would recommend to make it asynchronous:

```
var task1 = GetNodesAsync();
var task2 = GetAssetsToHandleAsync();

await Task.WhenAll(new Task[] { task1, task2 });

var result1 = task1.Result;
var result2 = task2.Result;
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to use result before. But I think the way I had it set up wouldn't allow it.