# collect output from Task.Whenall to a list/data-type

Tags: c#, websocket

I have the following c# code where i am sending a series of requests and reponses

```
public static async Task AuthenticateQvpx2()
{
    var handshake = new Handshake();
    foreach (var request in handshake.AutheticateStrings)
    {
        var buffer = _encoder.GetBytes(request);
        await Task.WhenAll(Receive(_webSocket), Send(_webSocket, buffer));
    }
}
```

The async functions Send and Receive, has the following code.

```
await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);

var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
```

I wish to collect the requests and responses into an array/ any form of data type.

I having trouble as I am not particularly sure of what i should do next?

Comment: What exactly you mean by request? You can definitely introduce some private concurrent type you should use from withing your methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Awaiting multiple Tasks with different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197699/awaiting-multiple-tasks-with-different-results)

Answer (score 1):

> I wish to collect the requests and responses

It's kind of odd to collect the *requests*, as that data is already right there (in the `buffer` variable).

Assuming you meant that you just need the *response*, you can do that using `await`:

```
public static async Task AuthenticateQvpx2()
{
  var handshake = new Handshake();
  foreach (var request in handshake.AutheticateStrings)
  {
    var buffer = _encoder.GetBytes(request);
    var receiveTask = Receive(_webSocket);
    await Task.WhenAll(receiveTask, Send(_webSocket, buffer));
    var response = await receiveTask;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense `await  Send(_webSocket, buffer); var response = await receiveTask;`?

Comment: @Magnus: In this case, yes, that would work. There are some scenarios where you do want the listener ("read") to already be wired up before you do the action ("write"), to avoid race conditions. But in this case, web sockets have a buffer, so the responses will not be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure based on your snippets what type of Tasks your `Send` and `Receive` return but generally you can get your results from multiple tasks after using `Task.WhenAll` using LINQ this way:

```cs
var handshake = new Handshake();

List<Task<WebsocketReceiveResult>> tasks = newList<Task<WebsocketReceiveResult>>();

foreach (var request in handshake.AutheticateStrings)
{
    var buffer = _encoder.GetBytes(request);
    tasks.Add(webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None));
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

var resultArray = tasks.Select(t => t.Result).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```cs
ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, (System.Byte[], WebSocketReceiveResult)> x = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, (byte[], WebSocketReceiveResult)>();
```

Generate GUID in your foreach a pass it to your methods:

```cs
foreach (var request in handshake.AutheticateStrings)
{
  var buffer = _encoder.GetBytes(request);
  var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
  await Task.WhenAll(Receive(_webSocket, guid), Send(_webSocket, buffer, guid));
}
```

Then you can work with dictionary from within your Receive and Send methods in natural way.

```
void Send(WebSocket webSocket, byte[] buffer, Guid guid)
{
  x.GetOrAdd(guid, new ValueTuple<System.Byte[], WebSocketReceiveResult>(buffer, null));
  await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None)
}

void Receive(WebSocket webSocket, Guid guid)
{
  var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
  x[guid].Item2 = result;
}
```