# Best way to make IO calls in parallel in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, asp.net-core-webapi

I am looking to optimize a function which makes a bunch of HTTP IO calls to other APIs and does something with the response. These API calls are not dependent on each other, so is there a way to execute them in parallel and get some performance gains instead of awaiting each of these calls one by one immediately?

This function is part of an ASP.NET Core Web API and is invoked for certain incoming API requests.

Option 1 - Make all calls individually and await them immediately

```
var res1 = await AsyncIOCall1();
var res2 = await AsyncIOCall2();
var res3 = await AsyncIOCall2();
<Do something with response>
```

Option 2 - Make all calls but await them later

```
var resTask1 = AsyncIOCall1();
var resTask2 = AsyncIOCall2();
var resTask3 = AsyncIOCall2();

//Now await
var res1 = await resTask1;
var res2 = await resTask2;
var res3 = await restTask3;

<Do something with response>
```

Option 3 - Use Task.Run

```
var resTask1 = Task.Run(async () => await AsyncIOCall1());
var resTask2 = Task.Run(async () => await AsyncIOCall2());
var resTask3 = Task.Run(async () => await AsyncIOCall3());

//Now await
var res1 = await resTask1;
var res2 = await resTask2;
var res3 = await restTask3;

<Do something with response>
```

What is really going to be the difference between these options and is there a preferred option?

Comment: I just put option 3 in there to confirm my suspicion that it is a bad idea - lmk

Comment: You probably want `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: Why is Task.WhenAll required? Cant I just await the individual tasks after firing them off?

Comment: @shivam-sharma it is almost the same as call them individually, but using `WhenAll` allows what the call into another `Task` so you are allowed to build chains like `.ContinueWith()` or gracefully handle exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between these options revolves around the concurrency and asynchrony of the operations.

Option 1 - Make all calls individually and `await` them immediately:

In this scenario, you're sending requests sequentially. You're sending the first request, waiting for the response, sending the second request, waiting for its response, and so on. This method isn't taking advantage of parallelism, so it's going to be the slowest method if the calls are not dependent on each other.

Option 2 - Make all calls but `await` them later:

In this scenario, you're initiating all of the requests "at the same time", and then waiting for the responses. This will take roughly as long as the longest single operation, which can be significantly faster than Option 1 if the operations are long-running.

Option 3 - Use `Task.Run`:

This approach isn't recommended for I/O-bound operations. The `Task.Run` method is generally best for CPU-bound operations where you want to offload some work to a background thread. But in this case, you're just creating unnecessary threads. The operations are already asynchronous and non-blocking; wrapping them in `Task.Run` doesn't provide any benefits, and can actually decrease performance by adding overhead.

For your scenario I would improve the options 2 by using `Task.WhenAll()`. After all tasks completed, you can pull the results out individually with `await` (see more details on this approach [Awaiting multiple Tasks with different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197699/awaiting-multiple-tasks-with-different-results/17197786#17197786))

```
await Task.WhenAll(resTask1, resTask2, resTask3);

// Now you can retrieve the results
var res1 = await resTask1;
var res2 = await resTask2;
var res3 = await resTask3;
```

Comment: Directly using the `Result` property is ugly, misses the point of the abstraction, and more importantly changes exception propagation dramatically. Just use `var results = await Task.WhenAll(resTask1, resTask2, resTask3);`

Comment: @AluanHaddad Right, but`var results = await ...` won't work if individual task values are of different types. see details https://stackoverflow.com/a/17197786/2091519

Comment: That's a very important point but if you look at the answers in that very thread you'll find the issue of exception propagation is addressed and this is necessary. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17197786/1915893 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/17197745/1915893