# What are there differences between assigning result variables INSIDE a Task.Run's closure versus OUTSIDE the closure?

Tags: c#, task

This is an offshoot of [Awaiting multiple Tasks with different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197699/awaiting-multiple-tasks-with-different-results).

Is this (setting result variables INSIDE the task):

```
var cat;
var house;
var car;

var catTask   = Task.Run(() => { cat   = FeedCat();   } );
var houseTask = Task.Run(() => { house = SellHouse(); } );
var carTask   = Task.Run(() => { car   = BuyCar();    } );

await Task.WhenAll(catTask, houseTask, carTask);
```

considered ill-advised or un-idomatic versus this (setting result variables OUTSIDE the task)?:

```
var catTask   = FeedCat();
var houseTask = SellHouse();
var carTask   = BuyCar();

await Task.WhenAll(catTask, houseTask, carTask);

var cat   = await catTask;
var house = await houseTask;
var car   = await carTask;
```

Edit 1: For the sake of simplicity, just assume `FeedCat()`, `SellHouse()`, and `BuyCar()` return strings. The thrust of the question is where variable assignment is taking place.

Comment: Without knowing what `FeedCat` etc do, it's really hard to know what's going on here. A [mcve] would make it easier to talk about *very specific* differences.

Comment: I renamed this question because you're really asking about closures, not Tasks.

Comment: Is `FeedCat()` an `async` method - or a normal (synchronous, not `async`) method? If the former then it should be named `FeedCatAsync()` and you (probably) don't need to use `Task.Run`.

Comment: @Dai I would guess OP is considering different implementations for methods, sync and async.

Comment: Don't get too into the weeds. Assume that the fictional functions are parallel-worthy and doing/returning the right things.

Comment: As a general rule, asynchronous code encourages functional coding patterns. The pattern of returning results rather than setting variables as side effects is more functional, so IMO it's nore natural here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *semantic* difference is definite assignment and typing; in the first version, you can't just use `var cat` - it won't have a type and the compiler will never know that it gets assigned. From the compiler's perspective, the lambda isn't known to have ever run, so definite assignment can't be used to prove anything useful.

The *implementation* difference will be that this forces `cat` to be "captured", which increases allocations, although in many cases you may not notice.

There's also a difference in terms of code readability; it is usually easier to understand (and test in isolation) something that *returns* a value, over something that updates ambient state.

Finally, note that *technically* the second version could run entirely non-asynchronously and sequentially, if none of the operations `await` anything (or return an incomplete task somehow else). The first version will get more parallel in those scenarios, but via more complexity.

Comment: OK, testability is definitely a strike against approach 1.