# How to run list of Tasks that return different data types by using Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, task-parallel-library

so i have two methods that are returning different data types. i want to run them at the same time. and get result from both of them.

```
public async Task<int> Ta1()
{
   await Task.Delay(100);
   return 100;
}

public async Task<string> Ta2()
{
   await Task.Delay(200);
   return "hello";
}
```

and main function where a create list of tasks and call it via Task.WhenAll

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
tasks.Add(Ta1());
tasks.Add(Ta2());

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            
var a1= //get value from Ta1;
var a2 = //get value from Ta2;
```

Comment: The tasks have already started. `Task.WhenAll` awaits already executing tasks, it doesn't start them. The only thing those tasks do right now is sleep though. After WhenAll, you can check each task's `Result` value

Comment: What's the actual problem you want to solve? A `Task` isn't a thread, it's a *promise* that something will complete and maybe produce a result in the future. The task returned by `Task.Delay` is triggered by a Timer that fires after the interval. The task returned by `Task.Run` actually represents a delegate that's executed by a threadpool thread (although even that can change)

Comment: i can do someting like that but dont know is it a good practise                                   
        var a = (Task<int>)tasks[0];
        var b = (Task<string>)tasks[0];

Comment: It wont be good in practice but I think that's the only way. Why do you want to do that anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
var ta1 = Ta1();
var ta2 = Ta2();
tasks.Add(ta1);
tasks.Add(ta2);

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

var a1 = ta1.Result;//get value from Tel1;
var a2 = ta2.Result;//get value from Tel2;
```

Comment: I'd prefer `await ta1` over `ta1.Result` as you can refactor more easily. The rule is to use `await` whenever you're in an `async` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the following helper method to make the usage a bit more streamlined

```
public static async Task<(T1, T2)> WhenAllCompleted<T1, T2>(Task<T1> t1, Task<T2> t2)
{
  await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
  return (await t1, await t2);
}
```

Usage

```
var (a1, a2) = await WhenAllCompleted(Ta1(), Ta2());
```

Comment: The `await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);` is redundant when you do `return (await t1, await t2);` on the next line. You might as well make it an extension method and write it like this: `public static async Task<(T1, T2)> AndWhen<T1, T2>(this Task<T1> t1, Task<T2> t2) => (await t1, await t2);`. Then you can do `var (a1, a2) = await Ta1().AndWhen(Ta2());`.

Comment: The `Task<(T1, T2)>` returns before it's completed so `WhenAllCompleted` does sound a little misleading.

Comment: The fault and cancellation behavior of just `return (await t1, await t2)` isn't equivalent to `await Task.WhenAll()`. I'd use `.Result` instead of `await` though

Comment: @Enigmativity the `await Task.WhenAll` is required. It is not redundant, for reasons discussed thoroughly in this question: [Awaiting multiple Tasks with different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197699/awaiting-multiple-tasks-with-different-results).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - For capturing errors?

Comment: @Enigmativity yep. For awaiting both tasks in case one of them fails. Without `await Task.WhenAll` it is possible for one task to become fire-and-forget, in case the other one fails.