# Deadlocks and async-all-the-way

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

While discussing a piece of code with a colleague, some questions came up about its reliability. The specific point of contention is the use of `Task.Run` and `Task.WhenAll` in the `CreateAxelAsync` method.

I'll cut to the chase. I have two questions about the code below:

1. Is it prone to deadlocks?
2. Does it break the async-all-the-way principle?

```cs
public record Vehicle( Axel FrontAxel, Axel RearAxel ) { }
    
public record Axel( IList<Wheel> Wheels ) { }
    
public record Wheel( float TirePressure ) { }
    
public static class VehicleFactory
{
   // async
   public static async Task<Vehicle> CreateAsync( int wheelsPerAxel )
   {
      var frontAxelTask = CreateAxelAsync( wheelsPerAxel );
      var rearAxelTask = CreateAxelAsync( wheelsPerAxel );
    
      await Task.WhenAll( frontAxelTask, rearAxelTask );
    
      return new Vehicle( frontAxelTask.Result, rearAxelTask.Result );
   }
   
   // async
   private static async Task<Axel> CreateAxelAsync( int wheelsPerAxel )
   {
      var wheelTasks = new Task<Wheel>[ wheelsPerAxel ];
    
      for ( int i = 0; i < wheelsPerAxel; i++ )
      {
         int wheelIndex = i;
         wheelTasks[ i ] = Task.Run( () => CreateWheel( wheelIndex ) );
      }
    
      Wheel[] wheels = await Task.WhenAll( wheelTasks );
    
      return new Axel( wheels );
   }
   
   // sync
   private static Wheel CreateWheel( int wheelIndex )
   {
      float tirePressure = CalculateTirePressure( wheelIndex );
      return new Wheel( tirePressure );
   }
   
   // sync
   private static float CalculateTirePressure( int wheelIndex )
   {
      float tirePressure;
      // perform some CPU-bound processing and assign to tirePressure
      return tirePressure;
   }
}
```

Comment: No to both, it's just parallel processing (all parallel CPU tasks contains `some` synchronous code).

Comment: _While discussing a piece of code with a colleague, some questions came up about its reliability_: Have you asked your colleague to re-write the code so that you can compare the differences?

Comment: It's pretty fine to call sync code within an async function. Doing the opposite may cause issues, though.

Comment: But why not: `return new Vehicle( await frontAxelTask, await rearAxelTask );` and skip `WhenAll`?

Comment: @user246821 I rewrote it to make it fully synchronous. It works fine either way.

Comment: ​@PoulBak omitting the `await Task.WhenAll` is wrong, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197699/awaiting-multiple-tasks-with-different-results). It opens the door for fire-and-forget tasks. It's not a matter of preference.

Comment: @arktos: _I rewrote it to make it fully synchronous_: The suggestion wasn't for you to rewrite the code, but rather your colleague. If he/she/they believe they have a better way (or believe that your code is incorrect), then he/she/they should write the code the way he/she/they want so you can discuss the differences. Also, then you'd have two code samples to post here which could be discussed. Have you had your colleague review your _new_ code to see that it represents what he/she/they were talking about?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: No it's not wrong, when you await each task as in my comment.

Comment: ​@PoulBak if the first `await` fails, the second task will become fire and forget.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: Use a `CancellationToken`, then it will be 'fail fast' . No need to await a task when you know the combined Task will fail.

Comment: @PoulBak in general you don't know whether an asynchronous operation will fail or not. And I have no idea how are you thinking to solve the fire-and-forget problem by using a `CancellationToken`. A problem that don't even exist if you do the correct thing and await both tasks combined with the `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: @PoulBak you could consider posting your suggestion as an answer, so that it can be evaluated (voted) accordingly. The [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) are not intended for answering the question. They are intended for asking for clarifications about the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're specifically asking about this line since it uses `Result`:

```
return new Vehicle( frontAxelTask.Result, rearAxelTask.Result );
```

In this case, the tasks are *already complete*, so there's no danger of deadlocking on the result. Similarly, since the tasks have already asynchronously completed, it's not blocking on async code; it is doing async all the way.

That said, I (personally) do prefer to use `await` to extract the results: either `await` each task, or assign the `await Task.WhenAll` result to a local variable and get the results from there. This is because the same code will compile if the `WhenAll` is removed, except then it *is* subject to deadlocks and *does* violate async-all-the-way.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. As I mentioned, the specific point of contention was the line `wheelTasks[ i ] = Task.Run( () => CreateWheel( wheelIndex ) );` in the `CreateAxelAsync` method.

Comment: That's a kind of parallel programming (dynamic task parallelism), which is fine. You may want to consider alternatives such as `Parallel` for more clarity and control (e.g., limiting parallelism if your thread pool gets saturated).

Comment: *"the same code will compile if the `WhenAll` is removed, except then it is subject to deadlocks and does violate async-all-the-way."* -- Removing the `WhenAll` would have negative consequences either way (it would open the possibility for fire-and-forget tasks). I have mixed feelings about making code intentionally more immune to vandalism. On the one hand it's based on realism and on the experience of life. On the other hand it's sad to think that your code might be maintained by vandals.