# Parallel.ForEarch - iterating through files in folders/subfolders, some files are missing/skipped

Tags: vb.net, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

Trying to get the CRC32 of all files in folder/subfolders and write the result in a simple text box, but in the process some files are skipped using the *Parallel.ForEach *loop.

The code:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Force.Crc32

Class Form1

    Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim myPATH As String = "E:\Temp" 'top path to be scanned
        Dim counter As Integer=0 'count of processed files
        Dim outputTEXT As String = "" 'entire output as text
        Dim stopwatch As New Stopwatch()

        'get list of all files
        Dim allFILES As String() = Directory.GetFiles(myPATH, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

        stopwatch.Start()
        ' Use parallel processing to compare CRC32 values
        Parallel.ForEach(allFILES, Sub(myfile)
                                       counter += 1
                                       ' Calculate CRC32 for the file
                                       Dim crc32Value As String = CalculateCRC32(myfile)
                                       outputTEXT += crc32Value & "," & myfile & vbCrLf
                                   End Sub)
        stopwatch.Stop()

        Console.WriteLine("files processed: " + counter.ToString + " |   time :" + stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString)

        txtISPIS.Text = outputTEXT 'populate txtbox with result

    End Sub
```

After processing folder with subfolders, containing 44.035 image files (.jpg), some files are missing from the result. And the count of missing files varies on different runs.

```
Six consecutive runs gave:
files processed: 43694 |   time :00:00:06.6360416
files processed: 43784 |   time :00:00:07.1502587 
files processed: 43822 |   time :00:00:05.6360439 
files processed: 43739 |   time :00:00:05.4827714 
files processed: 43744 |   time :00:00:06.5791734 
files processed: 43746 |   time :00:00:06.9342391
```

Using the *normal* **For Each** loop, works as is should and all 44.035 files are processed, but it's 10x slower, so the *parallel* option is much more interesting... :)

So, what I'm doing wrong?

Tnx

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75343790/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77760625/deadlocks-and-async-all-the-way/77760827

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try.  The order of the output will be random, the count should be fixed.

```
    Dim myPATH As String = "E:\Temp" 'top path to be scanned
    Dim counter As Integer = 0 'count of processed files
    Dim outputTEXT As New Concurrent.BlockingCollection(Of String) '<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    Dim stopwatch As New Stopwatch()

    'get list of all files
    Dim allFILES() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(myPATH, "*.*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

    stopwatch.Start()
    ' Use parallel processing to compare CRC32 values
    Parallel.ForEach(allFILES, Sub(myfile As String)
                                   Threading.Interlocked.Increment(counter) '<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                                   ' Calculate CRC32 for the file
                                   Dim crc32Value As String = CalculateCRC32(myfile)
                                   outputTEXT.Add(String.Format("{0}, {1}", crc32Value, myfile)) ' '<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                               End Sub)

    stopwatch.Stop()
    Console.WriteLine("files processed: " + counter.ToString + " |   time :" + stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString)
    txtISPIS.Text = String.Join(ControlChars.Cr, outputTEXT.ToArray)
```

Answer (score -1):

the issue here is that Parallel.ForEach can do things out of order and counter can be the same initial value for multiple instances

```
 Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     Dim myPATH As String = "E:\Temp" 'top path to be scanned
     Dim counter As Integer = 0 'count of processed files
     Dim outputTEXT As String = "" 'entire output as text
     Dim stopwatch As New Stopwatch()

     'get list of all files
     Dim allFILES As String() = IO.Directory.GetFiles(myPATH, "*.*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
     Dim crcs(allFILES.Count) As String

     stopwatch.Start()
     ' Use parallel processing to compare CRC32 values
     Parallel.ForEach(allFILES, Sub(myfile As String, ls As ParallelLoopState, count As Long)
                                    If counter < count Then counter = count
                                    ' Calculate CRC32 for the file
                                    Dim crc32Value As String = CalculateCRC32(myfile)
                                    crcs(count) = ($"{crc32Value},{myfile}")
                                End Sub)
     stopwatch.Stop()

     Console.WriteLine("files processed: " + counter.ToString + " |   time :" + stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString)

     txtISPIS.Text = String.Join(vbCrLf, crcs) 'populate txtbox with result

 End Sub
```

Comment: You may consider using [Parallel.For](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=net-8.0) instead as described in the post referenced above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75343790/10024425

Comment: good point on ConcurrentBag being not as performant. I've edited my post to use an array instead.
is Parallel.For that much faster than Parallel.ForEach?