# C# async method execute base on the first completed task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency

I have a program that will read some values from 2 readers located at different physical locations. For one reader I know I can write like:

```
private async void waitForReading()
{
    string result = await readFromReader1();    
    return result;
}

private async Task<string> readFromReader1()
{
    //poll until value detected
    return reader1Value;
}

private async Task<string> readFromReader2()
{
    //poll until value detected
    return reader2Value;
}
```

However, what if I read from two readers and resume execution when one of the task returned?

What I want to achieve looks like:

```
private async void waitForReading()
{
    string result = await readFromReader1() || readFromReader2();    
    return result;
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking into a similar question:
[Run two async tasks in parallel and collect results in .NET 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343081/run-two-async-tasks-in-parallel-and-collect-results-in-net-4-5)

I get inspired by Task.WhenAll method posted by [bart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/431878/bart), and find that Task.WhenAny(Task[]) is what I need.

Answer (score 2):

The basic answer to your question is to use `WhenAny`:

```
var task1 = readFromReader1Async();
var task2 = readFromReader2Async();
return await await Task.WhenAny(task1, task2);
```

However, there are a few additional considerations.

You mention "polling" in your implementation. This is the kind of operation that you'd probably want to *cancel* if the other reader has already returned a value. Consider using `CancellationToken` to enable cancellation.

Think about how to model the data coming from your "reader devices". If you always just want to query them on demand, then an `async` approach is fine. However, if their data can change at any time (which I suspect is the case), then you might want to consider setting up a *permanent* poll and consume it as an event *stream*; in this case, Reactive Extensions would be a more appropriate model.

Comment: my program did read values on demand by an operator pressing a button in control room, and yes I think I need the `CancellationToken`, but it seems I have to use `WaitAny()` instead of `WhenAny()`?

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `WaitAny`.

Comment: After reading the API doc on MSDN, I can't find a method signature of WhenAny() that takes a CancellationToken as parameter, may you point me how to make use of a CancellationToken with WhenAny()?

Comment: @OptimusFrog: You have to be careful what you're cancelling. Passing a `CancellationToken` to `WaitAny` will only cancel the *wait*, not your `readFrom*` operations. You need to pass a `CancellationToken` into `readFrom*`.

Answer (score 1):

How about `Task.WaitAny`

```
Task<String> task1 = readFromReader1();
Task<String> task2 = readFromReader2();
String result = Task.WhenAny(new Task[]{task1, task2}).Result;
```

Comment: I guess 

`Task<string> completedTask = Task.WhenAny(new Task[]{task1, task2});
Console.WriteLine(completedTask.Result);`

is more simple maybe?