# Running multiple tasks asynchronously and awaiting for their results c#

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

In my service layer I wanted to fire multiple methods asynchronously  and await for their results.

I tried with one at a time and it is erroring out.

In my **service class** I called the method like

```
var _validChapterCodesTask = gd.validateChapterCodeDetails(_input1);

await Task.WhenAll(_validChapterCodesTask);

var _chapterCodeResult = await  _validChapterCodesTask;
```

And in **DAL class** the method definition looks like

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<ChapterCodeValidationOutput>> validateChapterCodeDetails(GroupMembershipValidationInput gmvi)
 {
     Repository rep = new Repository();
     if (!gmvi._chapterCodes.All(x => x.Equals("")))
     {
         var _validChapterCodes = await rep.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<Entities.Upload.ChapterCodeValidationOutput>(SQL.Upload.UploadValidation.getChapterCodeValidationSQL(gmvi._chapterCodes),null);
         return _validChapterCodes;
     }
     else
         return new List<ChapterCodeValidationOutput>();
 }
```

**Error message**

> Error 208 The `await` operator can only be used within an `async` method. Consider marking this method with the `async` modifier and changing its return type to `Task<ARC.Donor.Business.Upload.GroupMembershipValidationOutput>`.   `C:\Users\m1034699\Desktop\Stuart_Upgrade_2.1_New Approach\Stuart_Export_Upload_v2.1\Stuart Web Service\ARC.Donor.Service\Upload\UploadValidationServices.cs    34  13  ARC.Donor.Service`

in lines

```
await Task.WhenAll(_validChapterCodesTask);

var _chapterCodeResult = await  _validChapterCodesTask;
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run two async tasks in parallel and collect results in .NET 4.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343081/run-two-async-tasks-in-parallel-and-collect-results-in-net-4-5)

Answer (score 1):

The error message is very explicit. It is telling you that you're **Service** class method is incorrectly attempting to use the `async` keyword. In order to fix this, you should be using ["Async all the way"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) as defined in Stephen Cleary's post on MSDN as a best practice.

For example, if you're service class has a method body that is working with `Task` or `Task<T>`, or attempting to use the `await` keyword the method signature for this corresponding method body must be `async` (as the `async` keyword enables a method to use the `await` keyword). Additionally this method itself should also be `Task` or `Task<T>` returning, with very few exceptions to that rule.

Personally, I would alter your **DAL** class to simply return the operation that represents the asynchronous work without actually awaiting it. If you think about it, the body of the `validateChapterCodeDetails` method does **not** actually need to do anything with the results, it just needs to return them (instead of materializing them there). Consider the following:

```
public Task<IEnumerable<ChapterCodeValidationOutput>> 
    validateChapterCodeDetails(GroupMembershipValidationInput gmvi)
{
     var rep = new Repository();
     return gmvi._chapterCodes.All(x => x.Equals(""))
         ? new List<ChapterCodeValidationOutput>()
         : rep.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync
               <Entities.Upload.ChapterCodeValidationOutput>
                   (SQL.Upload.UploadValidation
                              .getChapterCodeValidationSQL(gmvi._chapterCodes),null)
}
```

Since your `Task<IEnumerable<ChapterCodeValidationOutput>>` variable has already been awaited, you can access the `.Result` property to get what you're looking for.
Then in your **Service** class your method would look like this:

```
public async Task ConsumeAsync()
{
    var _validChapterCodesTask = gd.validateChapterCodeDetails(_input1);

    await Task.WhenAll(_validChapterCodesTask);

    var _chapterCodeResult = _validChapterCodesTask.Result;
    // Do something with it...
}
```

[Here is a .NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wwJz7G) that should help to exemplify this for you better.

**NOTE**

I would also caution using `IEnumerable` as it pertains to your repo, you should ensure that the results from the Database are not occurring via deferred execution, otherwise you risk the potential for connection issues, i.e.; unintentionally leaving a connection open, or not properly closing one.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Service` class where you call

```
var _validChapterCodesTask = gd.validateChapterCodeDetails(_input1);

await Task.WhenAll(_validChapterCodesTask);

var _chapterCodeResult = await  _validChapterCodesTask;
```

add a `async` to the method signature where `await Task.WhenAll(_validChapterCodesTask);` is called. And when this method also has a return type you have to wrap this type in a `Task` like the exception shows:

```
Task<ARC.Donor.Business.Upload.GroupMembershipValidationOutput>
```

E.g. if you have the following method:

```
public GroupMemberShipValidationOutput validate(..) {
   ...
   await Task.WhenAll(_validChapterCodesTask);
   ...
}
```

You have to change the method signature to:

```
public async Task<GroupMemberShipValidationOutput> validate(..) {
   ...
   await Task.WhenAll(_validChapterCodesTask);
   ...
}
```

Comment: Can you show me how to mark the method invocation async ? And I have already marked the method definition as `async Task<IEnumerable<ChapterCodeValidationOutput>>` right ? What is missing ?

Comment: You did it in the `validateChapterCodeDetails` method but you also have to do the same with the method where you call `await Task.WhenAll(_validChapterCodesTask);`

Comment: how can you for a variable ? You mean something like async _validChapterCodesTask ... that obviously errors out . Please help with the correct syntax.