# Entity Framework Task.WhenAll doesn't run task in parallel

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to seperate two methods with EF calls and combine them after completed

```
            var startDate = StartDate;
            var endDate = EndDate;

            var middleDate = startDate.AddDays((endDate.Day) / 2);

            var db1 = new DbContext();
            var db2 = new DbContext();
            var responsePart1 =  GetAvailableCalendarDatesAndSlots(db1, startDate, middleDate);
            var responsePart2 =  GetAvailableCalendarDatesAndSlots(db2, middleDate.AddDays(1), endDate);
            await Task.WhenAll(responsePart1,responsePart2);
            var finalResponse = responsePart1.Result.Concat(responsePart2.Result).ToList();
```

However when I view my log, seems like they're not running in parallel. 
For method GetAvailableCalendarDatesAndSlots, it takes 3 seconds to finish the tasks due to long date ranges. I'm planning to bring it down to 1.5 sec if possible.

How can I make them run in Parallel?

Comment: What does the implementation of `GetAvailableCalendarDatesAndSlots` look like?

Comment: [Task is not a thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html), so why would you expect it to run in parallel?  And since you are going to a database (which appears to be the same database) opening two connections is actually going to be less performant most of the time then reusing the same context.

Comment: It loop through the date range, get the timeslots available from db for the day & process logics. I placed a log inside the foreach method, seems like it doesn't run in parallel.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343081/run-two-async-tasks-in-parallel-and-collect-results-in-net-4-5 , they were suggesting the technique above to run in parallel using WhenAll.

Comment: @ErikPhilips, ADO.NET (which used by Entity Framework) will not open always open new connections every time, already opened connections will be reused.

Comment: if more result lay in one part of your range, then this part will be as slow as original. Better show the query `GetAvailableCalendarDatesAndSlots` generates

Answer (score -1):

```js
using System.Threading.Tasks;
class programe
{
 // db1, startDate, middleDate all should static variables
 private static R resdata;
 public  static async Task Main(string[] args)
 {
 Parallel.ForEach(GetSlots(db1, startDate, middleDate), async x =>
        {
  resdata.res += x;
 }

 }
 private static string GetSlots(db1, startDate, middleDate)
 {
 return GetAvailableCalendarDatesAndSlots(db1, startDate, middleDate);
 } 
}

public class R
{
public string res { get;set; }
}
```

Comment: please explain your answer and do not send just codes

Comment: @VahiD sir Actual I am weak in English and also I am the member before two days when I do no know the formats of the side.Try gradualy