# Handling asynchronous threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

I (think that I) understand the differences between threads and tasks.

- Threads allow us to do multiple things in parallel (they are CPU-bound).
- Asynchronous tasks release the processor time while some I/O work is done (they are I/O-bound).

Now, let's say I want to do multiple asynchronous tasks in parallel. For example, I want to download several pages of a paged response at the same time. Or, I want to write new data into two different databases. What is the correct way to handle the threads? Should they be async and awaited? Or can the async operation be just inside the thread? What is the best practice for error handling?

I have tried creating my own utility method to start a new async thread, but I have a feeling that it can go horribly wrong.

```
public static Task<Thread> RunInThreadAsync<T>(T actionParam, Func<T, Task> asyncAction)
{
    var thread = new Thread(async () => await asyncAction(actionParam));
    thread.Start();
    return thread;
}
```

Is this ok? Or should the method be `public static async Task<Thread>`? If yes, what should be awaited? There is no `thread.StartAsync()`. Or should I use `Task.Run` instead?

**Note:** Using `await Task.WhenAll` or similar approaches without an explicit new thread is not an option for me. The "worker" thread is run in background (to avoid blocking the main thread) and is later processed by other services in the system.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13542080/1663001

Comment: The asnwers are not exactly helpful for my case. I need to run a new thread explicitly.

Comment: Why do you need a new thread if you're downloading or running DB queries?

Comment: Because the threads are run in background and later processed in the system by other services. I gave simplified examples to focus on the asynchronous handling of a thread. Maybe I should have been more explicit that the thread is necessary.

Comment: You don't need explicitly create thread to run something in background `Task.Run(async () => await asyncAction(actionParam))`.

Comment: You still don't need a thread to run the IO in the background.

Comment: When you express concern about "blocking the main thread," what is the "main thread" in this context?

Comment: @mtkachenko "You don't need explicitly create thread to run something in background " That's true.  So then why did you provide example code that creates a new thread just to run something in the background?

Comment: @Servy `Task.Run` doesn't create a new thread. It schedule work item to be run on threadpool. And then threadpool will decide how to execute it.

Comment: @mtkachenko Which is *also* entirely unnecessary to run an asynchronous method.

Comment: @Servy You're right. `var task = asyncAction(actionParam);` is enough. Additionally it's useful not to forget about `SynchronizationContext`

Answer (score 1):

> I (think that I) understand the differences between threads and tasks.

There's one important concept missing here: concurrency. Concurrency is doing more than one thing at a time. This is different than "parallel", which is a term most developers use to mean "doing more than one thing at a time using threads". So, parallelism is one form of concurrency, and asynchrony is another form of concurrency.

> Now, let's say I want to do multiple asynchronous tasks in parallel.

And here's the problem: mixing two forms of concurrency. What you really want to do is multiple asynchronous tasks *concurrently*. And the way to do this is via `Task.WhenAll`.

> Using await Task.WhenAll or similar approaches without an explicit new thread is not an option for me. The "worker" thread is run in background (to avoid blocking the main thread) and is later processed by other services in the system.

This argument doesn't make any sense. Asynchronous code won't block the main thread because it's asynchronous. There's no explicit thread necessary.

If, for some unknown reason, you really do need a background thread, then just wrap your code in `Task.Run`. `Thread` should only ever be used for COM interop; any other use of `Thread` is legacy code as soon as it is written.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Threading.Thread` has been in .NET since version 1.1.  It allows you to control multiple worker threads within your application.  This only uses 1 core of your CPU.

The Task Parallel Library (TPL) introduced the ability to leverage multiple cores on your machine with `async` Tasks or `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T>`.

My approach for your "multiple downloader" scenario, would be to create a new `CancellationTokenSource` which allows me to cancel my Tasks.  The I would start creating my `Task<T>` and start them.  You can use `Task.WaitAll()` to sit and wait.

You should be aware that you can chain your tasks together in a sequence by using the `ContinueWith<T>()` method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
async class Program
{
    static bool DownloadFile (string path)
    {
        // Do something here. long running task.

        // check for cancellation -> Task.Factory.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested

        return true;
    }
    static async void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var paths = new[] { "Somepaths", "to the files youwant", "to download" };
        List<Task<bool>> results = new List<Task<bool>>();
        var cts = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();

        foreach(var path in paths)
        {
            var task = new Task<bool>(_path => DownloadFile((string)_path), path, cts.Token);
            task.Start();
            results.Add(task);
        }

        // use cts.Cancel(); to cancel all associated tasks. 

        // Task.WhenAll() to do something when they are all done. 
        // Task.WaitAll( results.ToArray() );  // to sit and wait. 

        Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to quit.");
        var final = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}